# use ReplaceAt inside a class

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I am building a wrapper for Shapeless HList and I'd like to use the `updatedAt` function to update a value in the HList, but I can't seem to get the implicits right. These are the two versions that I think are closest to a working solution:

```
class Data[L <: HList](val hl: L) {

  def updatedAtV1[V](n : Nat, value : V)(implicit 
         replacer : ReplaceAt[L, n.N, V]) : replacer.Out = replacer(hl, value)

  def updatedAtV2[V, Out <: HList](n : Nat, value : V)(implicit
         replacer : ReplaceAt.Aux[L, n.N, V, (V, Out)]) : Out = replacer(hl, value)._2

}
```

`V1` compiles, but because it returns a `Tuple` I am unable to force it to a `Tuple` type so I can't get `replacer(hl, value)._2` element. In `V2` the compiler cannot resolve the `Out` type.

Note that `V2` works OK, if the value is the same type of the type it replaces, but fails if it is a different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work with different type because of this implicit:

```
ReplaceAt.Aux[L, n.N, V, (V, Out)]
```

You're telling that you want to place a value of type `V` at `n`, and get `V` back out of HList. You can fix it by introducing extra type parameter:

```
def updatedAtV3[V, W, Out <: HList](n : Nat, value : V)(implicit
  replacer : ReplaceAt.Aux[L, n.N, V, (W, Out)]) : Out = replacer(hl, value)._2
```

There `W` - an element already in the list - can be anything (it will be inferred from implicit parameter), so everything works:

```
new Data(1 :: HNil).updatedAtV3(0, 42) == 42 :: HNil    
new Data(1 :: HNil).updatedAtV3(0, "foo") == "foo" :: HNil
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that bit.